# Google App Engine Standard Node JS how to run build script?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Does GAE standard for Node support a way to have build scripts? I tried using postinstall within package.json but that did not work.

My codebase has subdirectories with `package.json` within the subdirectories. In my root `package.json` there is

```
scripts: { 
    postinstall: cd vendor && npm install 
    ....
}
```

However I'm not seeing any vendor packages installed so I'm inclined to believe the postinstall does not get triggered on GAE Node standard.

Is there any way for me to install subdirectory dependencies without having to copy and paste all my `vendor/package.json` dependencies to the root?

Note: I've also tried putting an "install" within the package.json scripts but that didn't seem to get triggered either.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you must add them to the packages.json file which is with your other configuration files of your app. There is an article in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies) about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for your case, but seems like GAE standard has added the ability to [run a custom build step](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step).

However it does state:

> After executing your custom build step, App Engine removes and regenerates the `node_modules` folder by only installing the production `dependencies` declared in the dependencies field of your `package.json` file.

Maybe since the `node_modules` are in your `vendor/` directory, GAE may not detect and remove them, thus accomplishing your goal. This is a pre-install step, unlike `postinstall` specified in your script. Not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE standard, installation of dependencies are automatically managed. You should add them in your `package.json`.

As [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies) mentioned :

> When you deploy your app, the Node.js runtime automatically installs all dependencies declared in your package.json file using the npm install command.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Installation will be done during app deployment via :

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Comment: yes I saw that in the documentation but it doesn't talk about build scripts. What if I have a `postinstall` script that runs a command?

Comment: So you should probably consider to choose flexible env. What kind of post install you have to do ?

Comment: I have a vendor folder with a package.json. The postinstall does `cd vendor && npm install`. I need this vendor folder because my server serves static files from that `vendor/node_modules` folder. This allows me to serve static node_modules without exposing my entire `node_modules` folder.

Comment: In GAE standard, nodejs is executed inside a sandbox. You need to accept some limitations and adapt your solution if you want to use it. Static files should be served with GAE standard rules.  (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files)

Answer (score 0):

To add a build step, run the following:

```
gcloud beta app gen-config --custom
```

This will generate the default dockerfile and config that is run. In your .dockerfile, add your build step:

```
RUN npm run build --unsafe-perm || \
  ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then \
      cat npm-debug.log; \
    fi) && false)
```

Comment: This is valid only for App Engine Flexible which runs on docker containers. The OP mentioned he's using App Engine standard, which uses a sandbox environment [1].
[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/flexible-for-standard-users#application_execution

Answer (score 0):

"prestart": "if [ ! -d build ]; then npm run build; fi",

" -d build" here is the build process generated folder, replace it to whatever you actually use.